# How to show Search Overview in google analytics in php

Tags: php, google-analytics

How to show Search Overview in google analytics in php ??

Google analytics page shown

**Visits
76**

I am using this function **ga:organicSearches** link is here [developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#cats=visitor,session,trafficsources,adwords,goalconversions,platform,geonetwork,system,socialactivities,pagetracking,internalsearch,sitespeed,apptracking,eventtracking,ecommerce,socialinteractions,usertimings,exceptions,customvars,time)

I want to show this data inside my new analytics website but this function shows me **74 Visits**

May I know where I am wrong.

Here is my Code so far :-

```
$ga1 = new gapi($ga_email,$ga_password);

/* We are using the 'source' dimension and the 'visits' metrics */
$dimensions = array('source');
$metrics    = array('visits','organicSearches');

/* We will sort the result be desending order of visits, 
    and hence the '-' sign before the 'visits' string */


$ga1->requestReportData($ga_profile_id,
                       $dimensions,
                       $metrics,
                       '-visits', // Sort by 'visits' in descending order
                       $filter, // Filter the data
                       '2012-10-05', // Start Date
                       '2012-11-04', // End Date
                       1,  // Start Index
                       500 // Max results
                       );

$gaResults = $ga1->getResults();

$i=1;

foreach($gaResults as $result)
{
    printf("%-4d %-40s %5d\n",
           $i++,
           $result->getSource(),
           $result->getVisits());
}

echo "\n-----------------------------------------\n";
echo "Total Results : {$ga1->getTotalResults()}";    

echo "getOrganicSearches:".$ga1->getOrganicSearches().'<br />';
```

Is there any other function to show this data ???

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's the parameters I use to get organic search results (non paid visits from search engines)

```
    $params = array(
        'dimensions' => 'ga:source,ga:keyword',
        'sort' => '-ga:visits,ga:source',
        'filters' = 'ga:medium==organic'
    );
```

Notice that 'filters' line. It's value is set to **'ga:medium==organic'**.

This will return you the visits for organic traffic, you can do another call for paid to replicate the Search Overview page in Google Analytics web app.

Comment: what params do I need to get the paid traffic?

Comment: I believe changing the medium to 'paid' would work. Consult the docs though https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#cats=trafficsources

Comment: I've already tried using 'paid' but it gives me a syntax error. I've already checked the docs and medium only accepts `ppc`, `organic`, `referral` and `(none)`.

Comment: I have used `ppc` for my query [here](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/) and checked it on analytics but the result doesn't match. My query gives me 0 visit and on analytics page it gives me 1 visit.